# How to use larger images in TensorFlow OCR in Android?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, tensorflow, ocr

I'm working on a Java Android project that needs to OCR bitmaps with `width=1887` and `height=1061`.

I've managed to do this successfully with both [MLKit](https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/text-recognition/v2/android) and also [TessTwo](https://github.com/rmtheis/tess-two).

I'd like to do the same thing with [TensorFlow](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/examples/optical_character_recognition/overview).

I've downloaded the [recommended git repo](https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/tree/master/lite/examples/optical_character_recognition/android) with its Kotlin code. Kotlin is not my language though, so I'm struggling to figure things out in it. But I was able to get that sample running and working fine via Android Studio on my Android device.

Then, once I knew the sample worked, in my own project, I imported the following files:

- ImageUtils.kt
- ModelExecutionResult.kt
- OCRModelExecutor.kt
- text_detection.tflite
- text_recognition.tflite

I then wrote the following Java code and was able to get the process working successfully in my own app.

```
public static void ocrViaTensorFlow(Bitmap myBmp, Context context)
{
    try
    {
        OCRModelExecutor tfOcrExe = null;
        try
        {
            Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
            lock.lock();
            try {
                if (tfOcrExe != null) {
                    tfOcrExe.close();
                    tfOcrExe = null;
                }
                try {
                    tfOcrExe = new OCRModelExecutor(context, false);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("ocrViaTensorFlow-ERR-00", e.getMessage(), e);
                }
            } finally {
                lock.unlock();
            }

            lock.lock();
            try {
                if (tfOcrExe != null) {
                    try {
                        Log.wtf("ocrViaTensorFlow", "About to do TensorFlow OCR...");
                        ModelExecutionResult tfResult = tfOcrExe.execute(myBmp);
                        Log.wtf("ocrViaTensorFlow", "Items: " + tfResult.getItemsFound());
                        Map<String, Integer> itms = tfResult.getItemsFound();
                        StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
                        for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> itm : itms.entrySet())
                        {
                            String wrd = itm.getKey();
                            Log.wtf("ocrViaTensorFlow", "Item: " + itm.getKey());
                            output.append(" ").append(wrd);
                        }
                        Log.wtf("ocrViaTensorFlow", "TensorFlow Text: " + output.toString().trim());
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.e("ocrViaTensorFlow-ERR-01", e.getMessage(), e);
                    }
                }
            } finally {
                lock.unlock();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.e("ocrViaTensorFlow-ERR-02", ex.getMessage(), ex);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log.e("ocrViaTensorFlow-ERR-03", ex.getMessage(), ex);
    }
    myBmp.recycle();
}
```

However, the results were terribly subpar (words run together, missing words and letters, confusing order) and very, very, very slow (30-40 seconds).

Here is an example of an image being passed in to the process:

[image: Initial bitmap]

Obviously, the text I would like get from this is something like the following:

**Try "Alexa, play the trailer" Top Gun: Maverick (91512) IMDb 8.3/10 2 hr 13 min 2022 PG-13 X-Ray CC After thirty years, Maverick (Tom Cruise) is still pushing the envelope as a top naval aviator, but must confront ghosts of his past wen he leads TOP GUN's elite graduates on a mission that demands the ultimate sacrifice from ... Starring: Tom Cruise, Val Kilmer, Miles Teller Director: Joseph Kosinski Audio: Spanish, Japanese, Tamil, French, Portuguese, Kannada, Malayalam, German, Hindi, Polish, Italia... Resume Watch from Watch Add to More Ways Beginning Trailer Watchlist to Watch 1 hour 45 minutes remaining JOSEPH KOSINSKI AS DIRECTOR TOM CRUISE TOP GUN MAVERICK**

Instead, I get this image back:

[image]

And the OCR text results are as follows:

**resume beginning krk yalexaplaythetrailer erthirtyyears 2hrizmin2o22 tomcruisevalkilme josephkosinski 1915127 gune too watch elitegraduates edirector watchlist maverick**

I suspect these problems are at least partly because the Kotlin code from the Git repo appears to resize my bitmap from 1887x1061 to 200x31 for text recognition, and elsewhere appears to resize it to 320x320 for text detection.

I'm still struggling to understand the Kotlin code and what it does, but I tried changing those resizing variables to match the proportions of my images and got the following error:

```
Cannot copy to a TensorFlowLite tensor (input_images) with 1228800 bytes from a Java Buffer with 5334000 bytes.
```

I'm frankly surprised at how much more difficult this has been to implement than TessTwo or MLKit. Is there an easy way to adjust the `detectionImageHeight` and `detectionImageWidth` constants from the Git code without breaking the process? Is there an easy way to adjust `recognitionImageHeight` and `recognitionImageWidth` without breaking the process?

Or is there a better sample (preferably of Java code) that's more easily customizable out there somewhere?

Or, more directly, how can I get better TensorFlow OCR results for my bitmaps and also speed up the process?

In answer, I would really appreciate code samples, or links to code samples. Thanks!